# The curves $y = 6*5^x$ and $ y=9^x$ intersect at the point $Q.$ Show that the $X$ co-ordinate of $Q$ can be written as $x = 1+\log_3(2)/2-\log(3)5$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

No idea how to undertake this correctly, attempted various times but got nonsense answers, 2 earlier parts of Q were fine, looked over my workings but can't see the errors, a worked example would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
  6\cdot 5^x &=& 9^x \\
   \log (6\cdot 5^x) &=& \log (9^x) \\
    \log 6 +x\log 5 &=& x\log 9 \\
  \log 6 &=& x(\log 9-\log 5) \\
  x &=&{\log 6 \over \log 9-\log 5}\\
x &=&{\log 3 +\log 2 \over 2\log 3-1+\log 2}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

We want to establish

$$
x = 1 + \frac{\log_3 2}{2} - \log_3 5 
$$

Use 
$$
\log y = \log 6 + x \log 5 = x \log 9
$$

So
$$
x -1 = \frac{\log 6}{\log 9 - \log 5} -1 = \frac{\log 6 - \log 9 + \log 5}{\log 9 - \log 5} 
$$

Now you can take the logs to any base. Choosing the base 3 gives

$$
x -1 = \frac{\log_3 6 - 2 + \log_3 5}{2 - \log_3 5} = \frac{\log_3 2 - 1 + \log_3 5}{2 - \log_3 5} 
$$

$$
x -1 - \frac{\log_3 2}{2} = \frac{\log_3 2 - 1 + \log_3 5}{2 - \log_3 5} - \frac{\log_3 2}{2}\\
= \frac{2 \log_3 2 - 2 + 2 \log_3 5- 2 \log_3 2 - \log_3 2 \log_3 5}{2(2 - \log_3 5)} \\
= \frac{ - 2 + 2 \log_3 5 - \log_3 2 \log_3 5}{2(2 - \log_3 5)}\\
= \log_3 5 \cdot \frac{-2/\log_3 5 + 2 - \log_3 2 }{2(2 - \log_3 5)}
$$

Now in order for your conjecture to be corect, we need the last factor to be 1, i.e. we need

$$ {2/\log_3 5 - 2 + \log_3 2 } + {2(2 - \log_3 5)} = 0
$$

Now this is not correct, the result is 1.0662.